# System.Reflection.Emit not supported in Unity project with Mono scripting backend

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, mono, .net-standard-2.0

**Unity version:** 2020.3.23f1

**Scripting backend:** Mono

**API compatibility level:** .NET 4.x

**Player platform:** Windows standalone

I am trying to use the GitHub project [**Python.NET (Python.Runtime.DLL)**](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet), which targets **.NET Standard 2.0** and references **System.Reflection.Emit**.

I have imported both:

1. **Python.Runtime.dll** and
2. **System.Reflection.Emit.dll** (the .NET Standard 2.0 version)

...to my project.

My understanding is that **System.Reflection.Emit** [is not supported on Ahead-of-time (AOT) platforms/IL2CPP](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRestrictions.html), but should be fine with Mono backend.

However, **Python.Runtime** still throws a:

> PlatformNotSupportedException

...at any call from **System.Reflection.Emit**.

Is **System.Reflection.Emit** no longer supported, and if so is there a possible workaround or a way I could rebuild **Python.Runtime.dll** from source to avoid this problem?

Comment: _"Is System.Reflection.Emit no longer supported"_ - not it's still supported by MS (currently in .NET 7 not that that is relevant for Unity) and being part of .NET Framework 4.x and  .NET Standard 2.1 it's compatible with Unity. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html

Comment: What type of game are you making and what is the need for Python scripts?  What sort of things were you hoping to do?  Will this be like LUA scripting in the days of _World of Warcraft?_  The reason I ask is that _Reflection Emit_ is one of the technologies (the other being _CodeDOM_) in .NET that allows you to generate .NET binaries at runtime being able **to do anything** a C# developer could write at design-time.  Unless you have some form of .NET sandboxing these once Python scripts now .NET code could be malicious!

Comment: _"My understanding is that System.Reflection.Emit is not supported on AOT platforms/IL2CPP, but should be fine with Mono backend"_ - yes that would make sense because Unity can't _ahead-of-time_ compile that which does not exist and if it did we wouldn't need the Python. :)